# After deleting the module I'am getting "class does not exist" - magento2.3

Tags: magento2.3, customer, grid, customer-grid, action

I had created the dropdown action in the admin panel in the customer grid after that I had deleted the module but the view all customer page is getting an error in the admin panel as the class does not exist.

**Error:**

> {"0":"Class
> Arizon\AssignCustomer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ViewAction
> does not exist","1":"#1
> Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Arizon\AssignCus...')
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:54]\n#2
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Arizon\AssignCus...')
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:100]\n#3
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Arizon\AssignCus...',
> array('data' => array('config' => array('label' => 'Action',
> 'dataType' => 'actions', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...',
> 'indexField' => 'entity_id', 'viewUrlPath' => 'arizon/assigncus...'),
> 'name' => 'actions'), 'components' => array(), 'context' =>
> &Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context#0000000054bbb9a8000000007dad5e21#))
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]\n#4
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Arizon\AssignCus...',
> array('data' => array('config' => array('label' => 'Action',
> 'dataType' => 'actions', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...',
> 'indexField' => 'entity_id', 'viewUrlPath' => 'arizon/assigncus...'),
> 'name' => 'actions'), 'components' => array(), 'context' =>
> &Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context#0000000054bbb9a8000000007dad5e21#))
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:164]\n#5
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->createChildComponent(array('arguments'
> => array('data' => array('config' => array('label' => 'Action', 'dataType' => 'actions', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...',
> 'indexField' => 'entity_id', 'viewUrlPath' => 'arizon/assigncus...'),
> 'name' => 'actions'), 'components' => array(), 'context' =>
> &Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context#0000000054bbb9a8000000007dad5e21#),
> 'attributes' => array('class' => 'Arizon\AssignCus...', 'component'
> => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'name' => 'actions'), 'children' => array(), 'components' => array()),
> &Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context#0000000054bbb9a8000000007dad5e21#,
> 'actions', array('context' =>
> &Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context#0000000054bbb9a8000000007dad5e21#,
> 'structure' =>
> &Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure#0000000054bb89ba000000007dad5e21#))
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:145]\n#6
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->createChildComponent(array('arguments'
> => array('data' => array('config' => array('childDefaults' => array('storageConfig' => array('provider' => 'ns = ${ $.ns }, ...',
> 'root' => 'columns.${ $.ind...', 'namespace' => 'current.${
> $.sto...'), 'fieldAction' => array('provider' =>
> 'customer_listing...', 'target' => 'startEdit', 'params' => array('${
> $.$data.rowIn...', true))), 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...',
> 'storageConfig' => array('namespace' => 'current', 'provider' => 'ns =
> ${ $.ns }, ...'), 'componentType' => 'columns', 'editorConfig' =>
> array('clientConfig' => array('saveUrl' => '', 'validateBeforeSa...'
> => false), 'indexField' => 'entity_id', 'enabled' => true, 'selectProvider' => 'customer_listing...')), 'name' =>
> 'customer_columns')), 'attributes' => array('class' =>
> 'Magento\Customer...', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'name'
> => 'customer_columns'), 'children' => array('ids' => array('arguments' => array('data' => array('config' => array('component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'indexField' => 'entity_id', 'sortOrder' =>
> 10))), 'attributes' => array('class' => 'Magento\Ui\Compo...',
> 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'name' => 'ids', 'sortOrder'
> => 10), 'children' => array()), 'entity_id' => array('arguments' => array('data' => array('config' => array('dataType' => 'text',
> 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'componentType' => 'column',
> 'sorting' => 'asc', 'label' => 'ID', 'filter' => 'textRange',
> 'sortOrder' => 20))), 'attributes' => array('class' =>
> 'Magento\Ui\Compo...', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...',
> 'name' => 'entity_id', 'sortOrder' => 20), 'children' => array()),
> 'name' => array('arguments' => array('data' => array('config' =>
> array('dataType' => 'text', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...',
> 'componentType' => 'column', 'label' => 'Name', 'filter' => 'text',
> 'sortOrder' => 30))), 'attributes' => array('class' =>
> 'Magento\Ui\Compo...', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...',
> 'name' => 'name', 'sortOrder' => 30), 'children' => array()), 'email'
> => array('arguments' => array('data' => array('config' => array('dataType' => 'text', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...',
> 'componentType' => 'column', 'label' => 'Email', 'filter' => 'text',
> 'editor' => array('editorType' => 'text'), 'sortOrder' => 40))),
> 'attributes' => array('class' => 'Magento\Ui\Compo...', 'component'
> => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'name' => 'email', 'sortOrder' => 40), 'children' => array()), 'group_id' => array('arguments' =>
> array('data' => array('config' => array('dataType' => 'select',
> 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'componentType' => 'column',
> 'label' => 'Group', 'filter' => 'select', 'editor' =>
> array('editorType' => 'select'), 'sortOrder' => 50))), 'attributes' =>
> array('class' => 'Magento\Ui\Compo...', 'component' =>
> 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'name' => 'group_id', 'sortOrder' => 50),
> 'children' => array()), 'billing_telephon...' => array('arguments' =>
> array('data' => array('config' => array('dataType' => 'text',
> 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'componentType' => 'column',
> 'label' => 'Phone', 'filter' => 'text', 'sortOrder' => 60))),
> 'attributes' => array('class' => 'Magento\Ui\Compo...', 'component'
> => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'name' => 'billing_telephon...', 'sortOrder' => 60), 'children' => array()), 'billing_postcode' =>
> array('arguments' => array('data' => array('config' =>
> array('dataType' => 'text', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...',
> 'componentType' => 'column', 'label' => 'ZIP', 'filter' => 'text',
> 'sortOrder' => 70))), 'attributes' => array('class' =>
> 'Magento\Ui\Compo...', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...',
> 'name' => 'billing_postcode', 'sortOrder' => 70), 'children' =>
> array()), 'billing_country_...' => array('arguments' => array('data'
> => array('config' => array('dataType' => 'select', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'componentType' => 'column', 'label' =>
> 'Country', 'filter' => 'select', 'sortOrder' => 80), 'options' =>
> &Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Address\Attribute\Source\CountryWithWebsites#0000000054bbb929000000007dad5e21#)),
> 'attributes' => array('class' => 'Magento\Ui\Compo...', 'component'
> => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'name' => 'billing_country_...', 'sortOrder' => 80), 'children' => array()), 'billing_region' =>
> array('arguments' => array('data' => array('config' =>
> array('dataType' => 'text', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...',
> 'componentType' => 'column', 'label' => 'State/Province', 'filter' =>
> 'text', 'sortOrder' => 90))), 'attributes' => array('class' =>
> 'Magento\Ui\Compo...', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...',
> 'name' => 'billing_region', 'sortOrder' => 90), 'children' =>
> array()), 'created_at' => array('arguments' => array('data' =>
> array('config' => array('dataType' => 'date', 'component' =>
> 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'componentType' => 'column', 'label' =>
> 'Customer Since', 'filter' => 'dateRange', 'sortOrder' => 100))),
> 'attributes' => array('class' => 'Magento\Ui\Compo...', 'component'
> => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'name' => 'created_at', 'sortOrder' => 100), 'children' => array()), 'website_id' => array('arguments' =>
> array('data' => array('config' => array('dataType' => 'select',
> 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'componentType' => 'column',
> 'label' => 'Web Site', 'filter' => 'select', 'editor' =>
> array('editorType' => 'select'), 'sortOrder' => 110))), 'attributes'
> => array('class' => 'Magento\Customer...', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'name' => 'website_id', 'sortOrder' => 110),
> 'children' => array()), 'confirmation' => array('arguments' =>
> array('data' => array('config' => array('dataType' => 'select',
> 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'componentType' => 'column',
> 'label' => 'Confirmed email', 'visible' => false, 'sortOrder' =>
> 130))), 'attributes' => array('class' => 'Magento\Customer...',
> 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'name' => 'confirmation',
> 'sortOrder' => 130), 'children' => array()), 'created_in' =>
> array('arguments' => array('data' => array('config' =>
> array('dataType' => 'text', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...',
> 'componentType' => 'column', 'label' => 'Account Created ...',
> 'visible' => false, 'sortOrder' => 140))), 'attributes' =>
> array('class' => 'Magento\Ui\Compo...', 'component' =>
> 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'name' => 'created_in', 'sortOrder' => 140),
> 'children' => array()), 'billing_full' => array('arguments' =>
> array('data' => array('config' => array('dataType' => 'text',
> 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'componentType' => 'column',
> 'label' => 'Billing Address', 'visible' => false, 'sortOrder' =>
> 150))), 'attributes' => array('class' => 'Magento\Ui\Compo...',
> 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'name' => 'billing_full',
> 'sortOrder' => 150), 'children' => array()), 'shipping_full' =>
> array('arguments' => array('data' => array('config' =>
> array('dataType' => 'text', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...',
> 'componentType' => 'column', 'label' => 'Shipping Address', 'visible'
> => false, 'sortOrder' => 160))), 'attributes' => array('class' => 'Magento\Ui\Compo...', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...',
> 'name' => 'shipping_full', 'sortOrder' => 160), 'children' =>
> array()), 'dob' => array('arguments' => array('data' => array('config'
> => array('dataType' => 'date', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'componentType' => 'column', 'label' => 'Date of Birth', 'filter' =>
> 'dateRange', 'visible' => false, 'dateFormat' => 'MMM d, y',
> 'timezone' => 'false', 'skipTimeZoneConv...' => true, 'sortOrder' =>
> 170))), 'attributes' => array('class' => 'Magento\Ui\Compo...',
> 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'name' => 'dob', 'sortOrder'
> => 170), 'children' => array()), 'taxvat' => array('arguments' => array('data' => array('config' => array('dataType' => 'text',
> 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'componentType' => 'column',
> 'label' => 'Tax VAT Number', 'filter' => 'text', 'visible' => false,
> 'editor' => array('editorType' => 'text'), 'sortOrder' => 180))),
> 'attributes' => array('class' => 'Magento\Ui\Compo...', 'component'
> => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'name' => 'taxvat', 'sortOrder' => 180), 'children' => array()), 'gender' => array('arguments' => array('data'
> => array('config' => array('dataType' => 'select', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'componentType' => 'column', 'label' =>
> 'Gender', 'filter' => 'select', 'visible' => false, 'editor' =>
> array('editorType' => 'select'), 'sortOrder' => 190))), 'attributes'
> => array('class' => 'Magento\Ui\Compo...', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'name' => 'gender', 'sortOrder' => 190),
> 'children' => array()), 'billing_street' => array('arguments' =>
> array('data' => array('config' => array('dataType' => 'text',
> 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'componentType' => 'column',
> 'label' => 'Street Address', 'visible' => false, 'sortOrder' =>
> 200))), 'attributes' => array('class' => 'Magento\Ui\Compo...',
> 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'name' => 'billing_street',
> 'sortOrder' => 200), 'children' => array()), 'billing_city' =>
> array('arguments' => array('data' => array('config' =>
> array('dataType' => 'text', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...',
> 'componentType' => 'column', 'label' => 'City', 'filter' => 'text',
> 'visible' => false, 'sortOrder' => 210))), 'attributes' =>
> array('class' => 'Magento\Ui\Compo...', 'component' =>
> 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'name' => 'billing_city', 'sortOrder' =>
> 210), 'children' => array()), 'billing_fax' => array('arguments' =>
> array('data' => array('config' => array('dataType' => 'text',
> 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'componentType' => 'column',
> 'label' => 'Fax', 'filter' => 'text', 'visible' => false, 'sortOrder'
> => 220))), 'attributes' => array('class' => 'Magento\Ui\Compo...', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'name' => 'billing_fax',
> 'sortOrder' => 220), 'children' => array()), 'billing_vat_id' =>
> array('arguments' => array('data' => array('config' =>
> array('dataType' => 'text', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...',
> 'componentType' => 'column', 'label' => 'VAT Number', 'filter' =>
> 'text', 'visible' => false, 'sortOrder' => 230))), 'attributes' =>
> array('class' => 'Magento\Ui\Compo...', 'component' =>
> 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'name' => 'billing_vat_id', 'sortOrder' =>
> 230), 'children' => array()), 'billing_company' => array('arguments'
> => array('data' => array('config' => array('dataType' => 'text', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'componentType' => 'column',
> 'label' => 'Company', 'filter' => 'text', 'visible' => false,
> 'sortOrder' => 240))), 'attributes' => array('class' =>
> 'Magento\Ui\Compo...', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...',
> 'name' => 'billing_company', 'sortOrder' => 240), 'children' =>
> array()), 'billing_firstnam...' => array('arguments' => array('data'
> => array('config' => array('dataType' => 'text', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'componentType' => 'column', 'label' =>
> 'Billing Firstnam...', 'filter' => 'text', 'visible' => false,
> 'sortOrder' => 250))), 'attributes' => array('class' =>
> 'Magento\Ui\Compo...', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...',
> 'name' => 'billing_firstnam...', 'sortOrder' => 250), 'children' =>
> array()), 'billing_lastname' => array('arguments' => array('data' =>
> array('config' => array('dataType' => 'text', 'component' =>
> 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'componentType' => 'column', 'label' =>
> 'Billing Lastname', 'filter' => 'text', 'visible' => false,
> 'sortOrder' => 260))), 'attributes' => array('class' =>
> 'Magento\Ui\Compo...', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...',
> 'name' => 'billing_lastname', 'sortOrder' => 260), 'children' =>
> array()), 'lock_expires' => array('arguments' => array('data' =>
> array('config' => array('dataType' => 'text', 'component' =>
> 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'componentType' => 'column', 'label' =>
> 'Account Lock', 'visible' => false, 'sortOrder' => 270))),
> 'attributes' => array('class' => 'Magento\Customer...', 'component'
> => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'name' => 'lock_expires', 'sortOrder' => 270), 'children' => array()), 'actions' => array('arguments' =>
> array('data' => array('config' => array('label' => 'Action',
> 'dataType' => 'actions', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...',
> 'indexField' => 'entity_id', 'viewUrlPath' =>
> 'arizon/assigncus...'))), 'attributes' => array('class' =>
> 'Arizon\AssignCus...', 'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/gr...', 'name'
> => 'actions'), 'children' => array())), 'components' => array('ids' => &Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Columns\Column#0000000054bbba8c000000007dad5e21#,
> 'entity_id' =>
> &Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column#0000000054bbb857000000007dad5e21#,
> 'name' =>
> &Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column#0000000054bbb850000000007dad5e21#,
> 'email' =>
> &Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column#0000000054bbb9b0000000007dad5e21#,
> 'group_id' =>
> &Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column#0000000054bbb9e6000000007dad5e21#,
> 'billing_telephon...' =>
> &Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column#0000000054bbb9e7000000007dad5e21#,
> 'billing_postcode' =>
> &Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column#0000000054bbb9e0000000007dad5e21#,
> 'billing_country_...' =>
> &Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column#0000000054bbb9e1000000007dad5e21#,
> 'billing_region' =>
> &Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column#0000000054bbb9e2000000007dad5e21#,
> 'created_at' =>
> &Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date#0000000054bbb9e3000000007dad5e21#,
> 'website_id' =>
> &Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Websites#0000000054bbb9fd000000007dad5e21#,
> 'confirmation' =>
> &Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Confirmation#0000000054bbb9fe000000007dad5e21#,
> 'created_in' =>
> &Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column#0000000054bbb9ff000000007dad5e21#,
> 'billing_full' =>
> &Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column#0000000054bba597000000007dad5e21#,
> 'shipping_full' =>
> &Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column#0000000054bbb9f8000000007dad5e21#,
> 'dob' =>
> &Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date#0000000054bbb9f9000000007dad5e21#,
> 'taxvat' =>
> &Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column#0000000054bbb9d6000000007dad5e21#,
> 'gender' =>
> &Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column#0000000054bbb9fa000000007dad5e21#,
> 'billing_street' =>
> &Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column#0000000054bbb9fb000000007dad5e21#,
> 'billing_city' =>
> &Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column#0000000054bbb9f4000000007dad5e21#,
> 'billing_fax' =>
> &Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column#0000000054bbb9f5000000007dad5e21#,
> 'billing_vat_id' =>
> &Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column#0000000054bbb9f6000000007dad5e21#,
> 'billing_company' =>
> &Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column#0000000054bba590000000007dad5e21#,
> 'billing_firstnam...' =>
> &Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column#0000000054bbb9f7000000007dad5e21#,
> 'billing_lastname' =>
> &Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column#0000000054bbb9f0000000007dad5e21#,
> 'lock_expires' =>
> &Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\AccountLock#0000000054bbb9f1000000007dad5e21#)),
> &Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context#0000000054bbb9a8000000007dad5e21#,
> 'customer_columns', array('context' =>
> &Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context#0000000054bbb9a8000000007dad5e21#,
> 'structure' =>
> &Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure#0000000054bb89ba000000007dad5e21#))
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:238]\n#7
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('customer_listing',
> NULL, array('context' =>
> &Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context#0000000054bbb9a8000000007dad5e21#,
> 'structure' =>
> &Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure#0000000054bb89ba000000007dad5e21#))
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:140]\n#8
> Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent(&Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure#0000000054bb89ba000000007dad5e21#,
> 'customer_listing', array('attributes' => array('group' => '',
> 'component' => '', 'aclResource' => '', 'visibilityCondit...' =>
> array())),
> &Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor#0000000054bb883f000000007dad5e21#)
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:103]\n#9
> Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process(&Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context#0000000054bbb9bb000000007dad5e21#,
> &Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context#0000000054bbb82e000000007dad5e21#)
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php:81]\n#10
> Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(&Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context#0000000054bbb9bb000000007dad5e21#,
> &Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context#0000000054bbb82e000000007dad5e21#)
> called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:350]\n#11
> Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements() called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:129]\n#12
> Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php:55]\n#13
> Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called
> at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:65]\n#14
> Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:257]\n#15
> Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build() called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:882]\n#16
> Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('menu') called at
> [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php:26]\n#17
> Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu('Magento_Customer...')
> called at
> [vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index.php:28]\n#18
> Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index->execute()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:108]\n#19
> Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000054bb8b23000000007dad5e21#)
> called at
> [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:231]\n#20
> Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000054bb8b23000000007dad5e21#)
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]\n#21
> Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
> array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000054bb8b23000000007dad5e21#))
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]\n#22
> Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000054bb8b23000000007dad5e21#)
> called at
> [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:143]\n#23
> Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor#0000000054bb8f54000000007dad5e21#,
> &Closure#0000000054bb8f5a000000007dad5e21#,
> &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000054bb8b23000000007dad5e21#)
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]\n#24
> Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000054bb8b23000000007dad5e21#)
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]\n#25
> Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
> array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000054bb8b23000000007dad5e21#),
> NULL) called at
> [generated/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php:26]\n#26
> Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000054bb8b23000000007dad5e21#)
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:159]\n#27
> Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000054bb8b23000000007dad5e21#,
> &Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor#0000000054bb8f54000000007dad5e21#)
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:99]\n#28
> Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000054bb8b23000000007dad5e21#)
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]\n#29
> Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
> array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000054bb8b23000000007dad5e21#))
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]\n#30
> Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000054bb8b23000000007dad5e21#)
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]\n#31
> Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->__*callPlugins('dispatch',
> array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000054bb8b23000000007dad5e21#),
> array(array('default_store_se...', 'page_cache_from*...',
> 'storeCookieValid...', 'install', 'configHash'))) called at
> [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]\n#32
> Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000054bb8b23000000007dad5e21#)
> called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]\n#33
> Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]\n#34
> Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#0000000054bb8bd9000000007dad5e21#)
> called at
> [index.php:41]\n","url":"/admin_13akwq/customer/index/index/key/637ccb82ebd8f42ce8c6e344f27f3a23ceaf394097b9d47285edad2ac22d88b2/","script_name":"/index.php","report_id":"aba6e9488e09ad29e44fcf7e7b1e5e5d0b6ca5d09dabc41f24704af04224536c"}

Comment: Did you compile again after remove module?

Comment: @faisal Sheikh i had compiled after the removeing the module.